# What "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" " do in package.json in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

What concurrent do here ?

```
  "scripts": {
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
      "lite": "lite-server",
      "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts).

> The "scripts" property is a dictionary containing script commands that are run at various times in the lifecycle of your package. The key is the lifecycle event, and the value is the command to run at that point.

So the `start` command, will invoke the `npm run tsc:w` and `npm run lite` commands concurrently. More details on [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and the [run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) command.

The `npm run tsc:w` compiles your **TypeScript** and then watches for changes.
The `npm run lite` starts the npm server for the app in context.

Answer (score 3):

"script" property is used to specify command you can run on terminal.
on running    `npm run start`   in command line will concurrently cause:

1. your typescript compiler to run in watch mode (npm run tsc:w)
2. run your lite-server (npm run lite)

now you need to have **concurrenlty** as node package like this :

```
"devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0"
}
```

as dependencies/devDependencies in you *package.json* file in order to use concurrent as keyword.

**concurrently** allows you to

> Run commands concurrently

as stated here [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).